# Core data breaks randomly with nil

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift2

[NSManaged Object data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djg0L.png)

core data fails on relation entity fetch.

I am loading data with

```
 fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = true
        fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["Address"]
```

still I am getting exception. the swift doesn't allow me to ignore this error also. because of this my app crashes.

Error it give

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x1ca85c10 <x-coredata://5AE155F2-77DD-4C76-A1BF-B78CAAF8DE08/Address/p82>''
```

And I am checking with this before take values from this

```
if context.objectRegisteredForID(st.objectID) != nil
{
   var ss = st.city
}
```

But still fails. I don't know how to handle this.

If its other language I put try catch :(

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual exception message and line of code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: it not throwing any exception, only clue I have is attached image .

Comment: That is just a screen shot from the debugger. It says nothing. You said in your question you are getting an exception.  what does it show in the console

Comment: @Paulw11 i just added the message .

Comment: My guess is that one of your objects has a reference to an Address that can't be found

Comment: Yes that`s ok . but how to check that object is available or not ? , now it is simply breaking the app eventhough i checked for nil and objectRegisteredForID , objectwithID.

Comment: That error usually means that the persistent store file is not available for some reason. Are you doing anything to remove or reset the persistent store file, or messing with it in some other way?